# React Hooks: state variable having wrong value in event handlers, not able to type in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Below, i am rendering `<App/>` component with children as `<Input/>` component array. I added few inputs using "add new" button. I am able to add input text components. But, when i am typing value in text, it is not displaying. i am not able to modify object in state array since index is showing as "-1" in `setData` function. Due to this, value is not showing when we type in text box. Please let me know why `state` is `[]` when i am accessing in `setData` function.

```
    function Input(props)
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='variable'>Name</label>
                <input id='variable'
                    type='text'
                    value={props.value}
                    onChange={(e) => props.setData(props.id, e.target.value)} />

            </div>
        )
    }
    function App()
    {
        let [state, setState] = React.useState([])
        let [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState([])
        let setData = ((id, value) =>
        {
            console.log(state); // prints []
            let index = state.findIndex(ele => ele.key === id);
            console.log(index); // prints -1
            if (!(index === -1))
            {
                setState(state =>
                {
                    state[idx]["value"] = value;
                })
            }
        })
        let handleAdd = () =>
        {
            let idx = `${new Date().getTime()}`
            let tempState = {
                "key": idx,
                "value": "",
            }
            setState(state => [...state, tempState])
            let input = <Input key={tempState.key}
                value={tempState.value}
                id={tempState.key}
                setData={setData} />
            setInputs(inputs => [...inputs, input])
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleAdd}>add new</button>
                <div>
                    {inputs}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

When you create an `Input` component inside `handleAdd`, it creates a closure and as a result `setData` gets the state that existed when the component was created, missing the newly added state.

In general, creating components and saving them to state is not a good approach. Instead it's better to only save the data onto state and render the components based on it.

Here's one way to do this, note how much simpler the component and its logic are.

```
function App() {
  let [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  let setData = (id, value) => {
    const newState = state.map((st) => {
      if (st.key === id) {
        st.value = value;
      }

      return st;
    });

    setState(newState);
  };

  const addInput = () => {
    const idx = `${new Date().getTime()}`;
    setState([...state, { key: idx, value: '' }]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addInput}>add new</button>
      <div>
        {state.map((st) => (
          <Input value={st.value} key={st.key} setData={setData} id={st.key} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand on closure part, i still don't understand why we are not able to access state. As per my understanding, if there is a closure, it should be able to access values in parent function.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's not strictly a closure but basically `setData` doesn't know anything about state changes after it has been created since each instance of the component gets own instance of that function.

Comment: There is FAQ for using it in class components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) but i don't find same for hooks version. can you share any pointers to documentation or blog post, it would be great

Comment: Just google React closure issues and you'll find a lot of posts, here's one example: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/. I don't think you'll find anything specifically for your issue of creating components though since that's not how React is supposed to be used.

Comment: Thanks. I will be using the pattern you described.